# Python websockets lib client persistent connection (with class implementation)

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I'm trying to implement a websocket client in python using `websockets` and the apparently mandatory `asyncio` which I never used before (and I have a hard time to understand...).

I've read a lot on the subject and saw (too) many examples here and everywhere, but I can't find a way to properly make a websocket client with a persistent connection.

- I need to have a persistent connection because the commands need to be requested on the same connection, the first one being an authentication command.
- The remote server is a 3rd party API I don't have any control over.
- I suppose I could run an authentication request along with each command my program sends but that does not feel right to open > auth > request > close for each command instead of keeping one connection alive during the whole program's life
- My implementation is a library using many classes and I need to wrap the websocket connector/handler in one of them

Here's what I have right now, based on examples I found here and there (with some obfuscated data) :

```py
import json
import asyncio
from websockets import connect


URL = 'wss://server.com/endpoint'


class Websocket:
    async def __aenter__(self):
        self._conn = connect(URL)
        self.websocket = await self._conn.__aenter__()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        await self._conn.__aexit__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def send(self, message):
        await self.websocket.send(message)

    async def receive(self):
        return await self.websocket.recv()


class Handler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.wws = Websocket()
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def command(self, cmd):
        return self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__async__command(cmd))

    async def __async__command(self, cmd):
        async with self.wws as echo:
            await echo.send(json.dumps(cmd))
            return await echo.receive()


def main():
    handler = Handler()

    foo = handler.command('authentication command')
    print('auth: ', foo)

    bar = handler.command('another command to run depending on the first authentication')
    print('command: ', bar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Basically right now I get these answers (simplified and obfuscated) :

```
auth: Ok, authenticated
command: Command refused, not authenticated
```

I suppose my problem is that the block `async with self.wws as echo:` kind of create the connection, runs its code then drop it instead of keeping the connection alive. Since we are not using a usual `__init__` here but some `asyncio` voodoo I don't understand, I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your diagnosis is correct, the problem is that the async context manager it creating and closing a connection for each call of `Handler.command`  ... really not want you want.

Instead you could just synchronously establish the websocket connection during the init of `Handler` and then store the connection websocket (instance of type `WebSocketClientProtocol`) as a class member for later use, as in this sample code:

```py
import json
import asyncio
from websockets import connect

URL = 'ws://localhost:8000'

class Handler:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ws = None
        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        # perform a synchronous connect
        self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__async__connect())

    async def __async__connect(self):
        print("attempting connection to {}".format(URL))
        # perform async connect, and store the connected WebSocketClientProtocol
        # object, for later reuse for send & recv
        self.ws = await connect(URL)
        print("connected")

    def command(self, cmd):
        return self.loop.run_until_complete(self.__async__command(cmd))

    async def __async__command(self, cmd):
        await self.ws.send(json.dumps(cmd))
        return await self.ws.recv()


def main():
    handler = Handler()

    foo = handler.command('authentication command')
    print('auth: ', foo)

    bar = handler.command('another command to run depending on the first authentication')
    print('command: ', bar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How did you make it work? I'm getting `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'MainThread'.`

Comment: I just tried the same code, on python 3.9, and does work.